# How To Remotely Sign Out Of iCloud?

Tags: icloud

One of the top results in Google: *"How To Remotely Sign Out Of iCloud"*

https://www.addictivetips.com/web/remotely-sign-out-of-icloud/

I cannot find the **Settings app**:

[image]

The reason why I need it: I'm signed in on my work laptop. I don't want my employer to know. I prefer to log out remotely.

**EDIT:** Found it: https://www.icloud.com/settings/

[image]

Comment: If it is owned by your employer they may restrict doing certain things via their mobile management system that locks down company owned devices so they can only do things that the company wants them.

Comment: @SteveChambers employer manages their own devices. I was signed into my personal iCloud. That might be considered a breach of contract, using a personal account for personal notetaking. I will let the court decide. I will speak the truth, all the truth, nothing but the truth, will see what is the current state-of-the-art interpretation regarding the use of technology in a contemporary workplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings icon has been replaced with only text below your name. Simply hit `account settings` and you will be able to sign out.